# Is it possible to clone a Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox

I have a sandbox in which I've done a bunch of development work, and now I'd like to duplicate/clone it.  Is there a way to do that directly, or do I have to refresh from production and then deploy everything from the original sandbox to the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a [clone sandbox option.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_clone.htm&language=en_US&type=5)

Answer (score 11):

There isn't a way to 'Clone' a sandbox i.e. click one button to do it kinda thing.

You can deploy stuff across via

- Change Sets
- Force.com IDE
- Force.com Migration Tool

Or a combination of them.

Refreshes are only possible from Production to Sandbox.

(If you meant that the destination sandbox doesn't  already exist and you first need to create one, then yes you will need to refresh (provision) a sandbox from Production and then deploy to it)

Comment: That's what I expected, but good to have confirmation!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance ;)

Comment: @techtrekker Good news! Looks like Summer '16 is introducing the ability to clone a sandbox.  Check out page 307 of the Summer '16 release notes:   https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer16_release_notes.pdf    My page reference is from the preview version of the release notes, so the page number may change once the final release notes are out.  Since your answer already has 8 upvotes, I figure it's better for you to edit your answer than to create a new one.  :-)

Comment: @VivekM.Chawla go ahead and add a new answer, i think that's fine when information changes!

Comment: @Benj looks like I spoke too soon. The Sandbox cloning feature is getting pulled from Summer '16.  I'll come back and leave a new answer once the feature goes GA. Thanks!

Comment: @VivekM.Chawla It's live now, so you can leave that answer if you'd like.