# Building sandbox based on another sandbox

Tags: sandbox, eclipse, ant, change-set

We have created sandbox and made changes.We want to create copy of this sandbox.What is the fastest way to do this change? I can create one sandbox from prod and apply changesets from this sandbox but may miss couple of components which added by multiple developers.I am looking for  efficient way to do this.

Comment: Check this : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120574/sandbox-to-sandbox-copy-best-way

Comment: There's this one too: [Is it possible to clone a Sandbox?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/is-it-possible-to-clone-a-sandbox)

Comment: @martin sf pulled out that feature supposed to go with summer16.@javanoob It is refering same feature which is not currently available. I am basically looking best way to pull all metadata in one package.xml so that i can retrieve and deploy using Ant

Comment: In the link I posted, the answer was basically that there is no easy way to do it, but you could try doing it manually using the various deployment tools. ~4.5 years later, I believe that this is still the best answer.

Comment: As for pulling all metadata, it's ultimately impossible since there are [Unsupported Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm), but maybe you could try something like [selecting all components in eclipse, then using a tool like Kaleidescope(mac)](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63067/metadata-compare-is-there-an-easier-way-than-selecting-all-components-in-eclips)